# Bluetooth Devices in RecyclerView list

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to add Bluetooth Devices to a List to show it in a RecyclerView.Log.d is working but the List.add is unfortunately not working.

```
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
        result?.let { deviceFound(result.device)
            toast("Start Scan")
            Log.d("ScanDeviceActivity", "onScanResult(): ${result?.device?.address} - ${result?.device?.name}")
            list.add(BT_Devices(result.device.name,result.device.address,"0"))
            addDataSet()
            btAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
```

Comment: describe exactly what happening, if app crashing post logcat error also.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: result.device.name must not be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some Bluetooth Devices you might not get `name`.

Add `null` check for `result.device.name`:

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
    result?.let { deviceFound(result.device)
        toast("Start Scan")
        Log.d("ScanDeviceActivity", "onScanResult(): ${result?.device?.address} - ${result?.device?.name}")
        list.add(BT_Devices(result.device.name ?: "",result.device.address,"0"))
        addDataSet()
        btAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
```